# Google Colab bug: converts numerical values from a list to negative values

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

Am guessing this is some Google colab notebook bug that I am unable to repro if the code is run in a python terminal. Follow along and let me know if this is a bug and where can I report this?

```
import pandas as pd  
from scipy.io import loadmat  
!wget https://ai.stanford.edu/~jkrause/cars/car_devkit.tgz  
!tar -xf car_devkit.tgz  
cars_train_annos = loadmat('/content/devkit/cars_train_annos.mat')  
#print(cars_train_annos)  
data = [[row.flat[0] for row in line] for line in cars_train_annos['annotations'][0]]  
data[:10]  

-- output --
[[39, 116, 569, 375, 14, '00001.jpg'],  
[36, 116, 868, 587, 3, '00002.jpg'],  
[85, 109, 601, 381, 91, '00003.jpg'],  
[621, 393, 1484, 1096, **134**, '00004.jpg'],  
[14, 36, 133, 99, 106, '00005.jpg'],  
[259, 289, 515, 416, 123, '00006.jpg'],  
[88, 80, 541, 397, 89, '00007.jpg'],  
[73, 79, 591, 410, 96, '00008.jpg'],  
[20, 126, 1269, 771, **167,** '00009.jpg'],  
[21, 110, 623, 367, 58, '00010.jpg']]
```

Notice the values in bold above 134 and 167, they get converted to some negative values when I convert this list to pandas dataframe

```
columns = ['bbox_x1', 'bbox_y1', 'bbox_x2', 'bbox_y2', 'class', 'fname']  
df_train = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)  
df_train.head(9)



-- output --  
bbox_x1 bbox_y1 bbox_x2 bbox_y2 class name  
0 39 116 56 375 14 00001.jpg  
1 36 116 868 587 3 00002.jpg  
2 85 109 601 381 91 00003.jpg  
3 621 393 1484 1096 **-122** 00004.jpg  
4 14 36 133 99 106 00005.jpg  
5 259 289 515   416 123 00006.jpg  
6 88 80 541 397 89 00007.jpg  
7 73 79 591 410 96 00008.jpg
8 20 126 1269 771 **-89** 00009.jpg
```

The above values got converted to some negative values(highlighted with **). The same code works fine if you run it via the Python terminal.
Is this a bug or am I missing something here?

Comment: 134 + 122 = 256, 
167 + 89 = 256...
I smell an signed/unsigned integer mixup somewhere along the way.

Comment: Confirmed: the integers in your source data are stored in `uint8` and `uint16`. Pandas DataFrame constructor infers `Int` and converts them on the fly. Try: `df_train = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns, dtype=pd.UInt16Dtype)`. It should work, but I'd suggest to properly convert to `Int` in an intermediate step.

Comment: It seems like it is ineed a bug in the 1.3.5 version of pandas which colab uses. If you revert to an older version (`!pip install pandas==1.0.0` and the restart the runtime) and then run your code - it works fine.

Comment: Ahh ha, Thank you @JacekJaskólski that worked, I installed panda 1.0.0 and it worked fine. Thank you for looking into it.